# Can't figure out why it keeps running my loop

Tags: python

im a beginner in python. I wrote a small program that play the game roulette (from the casino) but its a simplified version.

I can't figure out why it keeps running the wrong loop when i try it. When i "place my bet" it keeps running the loop but i've no idea why ?

```
from math import ceil
from random import randrange

print '=================='
print '    Roulette v2   '
print '=================='

# init vars
bet = 0
pick = 0
restart = 1
paire = 0
keep = True
bille = randrange(50)

wallet = raw_input('Whats in your wallet : ') # ask the player how much money he gets for this session

try:
    wallet = int(wallet) # set wallet as integer, also test if user wrote a number
except ValueError:
    print '[!] It must be a number' # if not a number set a default value for wallet
    print '[!] Default value set to 50'
    wallet = 50 # 50 is our default value

while keep and restart: # while keep is true and restart equal 1,then keep playing

    print 'Wallet : ',wallet,'$' # show how much money we got left
    bet = raw_input('Place a bet : ') 

    while type(bet) != int: # same as above, check if bet is an integer

        try:
            bet = int(bet)
        except ValueError:
            print '[!] It must be a number'

        bet = raw_input('Place a bet : ') # if not, ask again

        while bet > wallet: # if not enough money then cancel bet
            print '[!] You do not have ',bet,'$ in your wallet !'
            print 'Your wallet : ',wallet
            bet = raw_input('Place a bet : ')

    pick = raw_input('Pick a number between 1-50 : ')

    while type(pick) != int: # same as above

        try:
            pick = int(pick)
        except ValueError:
            print '[!] It must be a number'

        pick = raw_input('Pick a number between 1-50 : ')

    print '...'
    print '....'
    print '.....'
    print '......!'

    if pick != bille: # if players number is different than random integer
        paire = pick % 2 # check if players number is pair

        if paire == 1: # if its pair then add bet + bet / 2 to his wallet
            print 'Your number is pair !'
            bet = bet + bet / 2
            ceil(bet) # we dont want a float number
            wallet = wallet + bet
            print 'You won : ',bet

        elif paire == 0: # else if number is odd, player loose his money
            print 'Your number is odd !'
            wallet = wallet - bet

    elif pick == bille: # if players number equal to random integer
        print 'J A C K P O T !!!'
        bet = bet * 3
        wallet = wallet + bet # then bet * 3 and add to players wallet
        print 'You won : ',bet

    if wallet < 0: # if players wallet empty then end of the game
        print '[!] You have no money left !'
        print '[!] You are out of the game !'
        keep = False # loop stop if keep isnt true
        restart = 0

    elif wallet > 0: # if player has no money left in his wallet
        restart = raw_input('Keep playing [o/n] ? ')

        try:
            str(restart)
        except TypeError:
            print '[!] Wrong answer !'

        while type(restart) != str:
            print '[!] Wrong answer !'
                        restart = raw_input('Keep playing [o/n] ? ')
            str(restart)

        if type(restart) == str:

            if restart == 'o':
                restart = 1

            elif restart == 'n':
                restart = 0
                Keep = False

        elif type(restart) != str:
            print '[!] Wrong answer !'





print '[!] Bye...' # just a test
```

Comment: You are asking for `bet` again even when it correctly parsed as an `int`. Same with `pick`

Comment: Oh lol i guess im a bit too tired it was a stupid mistake haha.. I'll pay more attention to tabulations now! thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You're asking bet a second time, but you forget to cast it into `int` then you compare and loop (`while bet > wallet`).

The problem is that, in Python 2 with the standard CPython interpreter, this comparison is always `True` since comparing objects of different types will just compare types (and `str > int`); see [comment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) about this implementation detail.

However, that's not the case anymore in Python 3 and it would give a `TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()` exception that would have made your issue clearer.

Comment: Good observation. Minor correction, though: While OP is indeed using Python 2, In Python 3, comparing `int` and `str` will give a `TypeError`, so it is not _always_ `True`.